# running tcpdump from android application

Tags: android

I want to develop an android application that will be able to launch tcpdump. Can any one give me any suggestion regarding this issue?

thanks
kaisar

Comment: is there a non-root app available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shark for root exist for android OS, it based on tcpdump.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=725692

Answer (score 0):

you can cross-compile TCPDUMP and PCAP in unbutu or debian to make it available for Android as a non-installed folder which you browse to with a terminal emulator to run the tcpdump commands. has to be a rooted device for wifi monitor mode. Great tutorial for this can be found here:http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/monitoring-android-network-traffic-part-i-installing-toolchain